# Align to the right of the screen with margin Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a Linearlayout within a RelativeLayout that I'm trying to align to the rightmost side of the screen with margin. Example:

[image]

How should I modify the LinearLayout's properties to achieve this? thanks

Here is the XML file(the name of the LinearLayout that should be aligned to right is slide_right):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

     <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/slide_left"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-367dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:background="@drawable/left_slide"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/slide_right"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="-30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:background="@drawable/right_slide">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_linear_l"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/mapbt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mapbt" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/profilebt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/profilebt" />



        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/settingsbt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/settingsbt" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/optionalbt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/optionbt" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/lvlbt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/levelbt" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/experiencebar"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/Attack_Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/slide_left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="129dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/slide_left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_old"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: NO Need to post your your XML File, See My(Shridutt Kothari)'s Answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change Your `Relative layout's Property`

from

```
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to

```
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

thats it... (definitely I have tested it **see below snapshot**)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's working as expected now. here is the promised upvote :)

Comment: Cool.. Nice Helping people.
+1 to shridutt for extra effort of posting image and fast reply.
I love StackTrace just because of these helping people...

Answer (score 0):

See the following Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/your_relative_layout_id"        
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/your_linear_layout_id"
        android:layout_width="50dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="-30dip"
        android:background="#e42c2a"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_marginRight="-30dip"
```

are of your use.

Comment: Same, i tried this approach - android:layout_marginRight has no effect. I will include my layout XML in the first post.

Comment: I thnink if you had read the above xml it was sufficient for your solution as it was also containing the match parent property in the relative layout....
But you dint read it... and i had to write the new answer again for you.. but no problem.
Suggestion:In future pls always read full answer and also carefully.